# Not showing Code Coverage on SonarQube Dashboard when I pass output(xml file) generated by nunit3-console

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, nunit-3.0

I run testcases on `Jenkins` using `nunit3-console.exe`. Some test Cases fails but `nunit-result.xml` is generated.

When testcases fails `Jenkins` job is exited with **error code -2**. So I put a `EXIT 0` which continue the `Jenkins` jobs, I a still getting `nunit output` file that is `nunit-result.xml`.

Then I pass this xml file to sonar-scanner so that I can see code Coverage on `SonarQube` Dashboard.

Everything work fine. `Jenkins` job is Successful. But I can't see Code Coverage on `SonarQube` DashBoard.

Command to generate output file (`nunit-result.xml`) :

```
(path)\\nunit3-console.exe (path)\\Test.Common.dll --result=(path)nunit-result.xml;format=nunit2
"Test.commom.dll" is Test case File.
"nunit-result.xml is output file generated.



Before It was giving error that <test-result> element not found then I put "format=nunit2" which gave me right output.

After this I run this code:- 

(path)\\sonar-scanner 
-Dsonar.projectKey=${projectKey} 
-Dsonar.projectName=${projectKey} 
-Dsonar.organization=organization
-Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.(server-path).com 
-Dsonar.login=username
-Dsonar.password=pasword
-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 
-Dsonar.sources=. 
-Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0  
-Dsonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=(path)\\nunit-result.xml 
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/bin/**,**/obj/**,**/node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts"
```

I should see Code Coverage on `SonarQube` Dashboard after this. But I see all other things except Code Coverage.

P.S. :  Is used **"(path)"** for just example I am replacing it with proper file path ?

[image: ScreenShot of SonarQube Dashboard]